# Spring MVC: Form Not Submitting

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, form-submit

In my Spring MVC application, the Form Controller is correctly wired and displays the form as intended.

But the Submit button does not work. Moreover, the onSubmit() method of the FormController never gets invoked, because my debug print statements are not shown.

Instead, when I click Submit, the form re-loads and some of the fields get changed (very strange behavior).

I implemented my FormController as usual in Spring MVC:

```
public class RegisterController extends SimpleFormController {

    public RegisterController()
    {
        setCommandClass(Customer.class);
        setCommandName("customer");
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
        // never gets run!
        Customer customer = (Customer) command;
        System.out.println("TEST. Obtained Customer object: " + customer.toString());
    }
}
```

My bean wiring for the Dispatcher Servlet is:

```
<bean name="/register.htm" class="techbooks.web.RegisterController"
    p:formView="register" p:successView="home"/>
```

"register" refers to register.htm(.jsp) and "home" to home.htm(.jsp), both of which exist.

JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TechBooks.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>

<center>

<table style="width: 850px" class="style2">
<form:form method="POST" commandName="customer">
    <tr>
    <td><h1>Register New Customer</h1></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer ID:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerId"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer Password:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:password path="customerPassword"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer First Name:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerFirstName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer Last Name:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerLastName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer Address:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerAddress"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer City:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerCity"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer State:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerState"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer Zip Code:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerZipCode"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Customer Email Address:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerEmailAddress"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Date Added:</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:input path="customerDateAdded" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Is Admin?</td>
                    <td align="left"><form:checkbox path="customerIsAdmin"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="Register"/><br/><input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>

</form:form>
</table>


</center>

</body>

</html>
```

Customer bean class:

```
package techbooks.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String customerId;
    private String customerPassword;
    private String customerFirstName;
    private String customerLastName;
    private String customerAddress;
    private String customerCity;
    private String customerState;
    private String customerZipCode;
    private String customerEmailAddress;
    private Date customerDateAdded;
    private Boolean customerIsAdmin;

    /**
     * @return the customerId
     */
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerId the customerId to set
     */
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerPassword
     */
    public String getCustomerPassword() {
        return customerPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerPassword the customerPassword to set
     */
    public void setCustomerPassword(String customerPassword) {
        this.customerPassword = customerPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerFirstName
     */
    public String getCustomerFirstName() {
        return customerFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerFirstName the customerFirstName to set
     */
    public void setCustomerFirstName(String customerFirstName) {
        this.customerFirstName = customerFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerLastName
     */
    public String getCustomerLastName() {
        return customerLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerLastName the customerLastName to set
     */
    public void setCustomerLastName(String customerLastName) {
        this.customerLastName = customerLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerAddress
     */
    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerAddress the customerAddress to set
     */
    public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerCity
     */
    public String getCustomerCity() {
        return customerCity;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerCity the customerCity to set
     */
    public void setCustomerCity(String customerCity) {
        this.customerCity = customerCity;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerState
     */
    public String getCustomerState() {
        return customerState;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerState the customerState to set
     */
    public void setCustomerState(String customerState) {
        this.customerState = customerState;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerZipCode
     */
    public String getCustomerZipCode() {
        return customerZipCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerZipCode the customerZipCode to set
     */
    public void setCustomerZipCode(String customerZipCode) {
        this.customerZipCode = customerZipCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerEmailAddress
     */
    public String getCustomerEmailAddress() {
        return customerEmailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerEmailAddress the customerEmailAddress to set
     */
    public void setCustomerEmailAddress(String customerEmailAddress) {
        this.customerEmailAddress = customerEmailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerDateAdded
     */
    public Date getCustomerDateAdded() {
        return customerDateAdded;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerDateAdded the customerDateAdded to set
     */
    public void setCustomerDateAdded(Date customerDateAdded) {
        this.customerDateAdded = customerDateAdded;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerIsAdmin
     */
    public Boolean getCustomerIsAdmin() {
        return customerIsAdmin;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerIsAdmin the customerIsAdmin to set
     */
    public void setCustomerIsAdmin(Boolean customerIsAdmin) {
        this.customerIsAdmin = customerIsAdmin;
    }
}
```

As I said, the form never gets submitted, and the onSubmit() of the Controller never executes. Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Spring MVC 2.5.   Thanks

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript code that is executed when you press submit button?

Comment: can you put in your jsp code so that we can better understand the flow ?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I added the JSP code and also the Bean Class.

Comment: No, there is no JavaScript anywhere.

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but where is the return statement of your onSubmit()???

Comment: Hi Boris, I forgot to include it. I return a ModelAndView. But it doesn't matter, the method itself never executes, because the very first debug print statement is never shown. If there were errors in the onSubmit() I would see them.

Comment: Are there any other Controller methods overriden?If so it would be nice to see the entire source of RegisterController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be some binding errors so I suggest to override

```
protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request,
                                             HttpServletResponse response,
                                             Object command,
                                             BindException errors)
                                      throws Exception
```

and check that errors.hasErrors() returns false, just to be sure that the submission was successful.

See [processFormSubmission](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html#processFormSubmission%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.springframework.validation.BindException%29)

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. processFormSubmission() uncovered a Date field conversion error. I'll fix it, it was in the CustomerDateAdded date field, conversion from string to Date.

Answer (score 0):

Further to above accepted answer I would like to point out a few thing -

If you have overridden

> protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request, Object command, Errors errors)

method in your controller which is typically invoked on a `GET` request will be called even when the form is submitted (POST). This is because if there are any Binding error form will be reloaded calling `referecenData()` again. Ofcourse you can override `processFormSubmission()` method but if you are just interested in overriding `onSubmit()` method I suggest override

> protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)

method and see the `BindException` error.